# How do I get random number from a function without getting another random number?

Tags: node.js, json, function, discord, discord.js

I know I worded it kinda weirdly but I'm not entirely sure how to explain it without visuals. I'm sure I'm going about this in a super complicated way. I'm trying to randomly get a Pokemon to spawn in the server to then be able to catch the Pokemon that spawns.

I found the best way to be able to get the name and send the image was to make a few different functions to return each piece that I need at separate places

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const pokemon = require('./pokemon.json');

module.exports = {
    getPokemon: function (randomPokemon) {
        randomPokemon = pokemon[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon.length)];

        return randomPokemon;
    },

    pokemonImage: function (pokeImage) {
        pokeImage = new Discord.MessageAttachment((this.getPokemon()).image)

        return pokeImage;
    },

    pokemonName: function (pokeName) {
        pokeName = (this.getPokemon()).name;

        return pokeName;
    },

    sendPokemon: function (message) {
        return message.channel.send(this.pokemonImage());
    }
}
```

The problem is, when a message is sent, it gets a pokemon and displays it in the server perfectly. But when I go to catch it, I'm calling the pokemonName function which then generates a new random pokemon from the list which instead shows that my answer is wrong.

How do I get the name from the number that was already generated without generating a new random number each time I try to catch them?

Here is the command that is used to catch the Pokemon. Obviously it's grabbing a new random Pokemon every time the command is used but this is where I would like o figure out what I should do.

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');
const functions = require('../functions.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'catch',
    description: 'Used to catch a Pokemon that spawns',
    execute(message, args) {
        args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
        
        if (args[1] == functions.pokemonName()) {
            return message.channel.send('That\'s right!');
        }else {
            message.channel.send('That\'s wrong! Try again.');
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: There isn't really enough of your code structure to understand the overall flow or where you can persist things, but it seems likely that you need to store the first random pokemon, perhaps in some instance data and the other methods can check to see if there's already a stored pokemon and, if so, use it rather than generate a new random one.

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to do really but I’m not sure how to go about that. Is there other code you need to see to understand what I’m trying to do better?

Comment: For starters, show us the code where this code is called from and how its used.